# Play video on Swift Error

Tags: swift, xcode, url, video

I'm trying to play a video using swift, however the line of code below gives me an error

**init(URL:)' has been renamed to init(url:)'**

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path) as URL)
```

How can  modify this line to get ride of the error.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if let player = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "The name of your file", withExtension: "mp4"){
        if NSWorkspace.shared().open(player) {

        }
    }
```

Be sure to substitute the name of your file and file type. You may want to put it in a function and call that function.

I know it's a totally different way of doing it, but it's always worked for me. I recommend trying it.